# Process Text File using Saved Conditions or Criteria in DB

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask on how to process a large text file (INPUT.txt) which contains data separated by enter (vbCRLF) and process data based on criteria or conditions stored on separate table (dbCRITERIA). Here is an example test cases or data:

> SLSID 101
>   TRNDATE 2017-09-01
>   AMTPAID 1000
>   AMTCHRG 750
>   PTYPE Cash
>   ...
>   Several copies up to 100 records

```
dbCRITERIA (Table Records)
cID  SQLCondition
1    (TRNDATE IS NOT NULL AND TRNDATE='2017-09-01')
2    (AMTPAID > 0 AND AMTCHRG > 0)
3    ((AMTPAID - AMTCHRG) >= 0)
4    (PTYPE = 'Check')
```

All the conditions or criteria in the said table will be used to process each record in the text file. How should I approached the process in doing it in VB.NET?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "conditions".  The parenthetical stuff there is garden variety logic, typically applied in *code*.  I'd read it into a class which applies those rules.  A `ResultCode` might indicate which rule is violated for those that dont pass (like the sample data given...PTYPE is not 'Check')

Comment: What I mean conditions are those records stored in the table will be used to check each records in the input. There are several types of PTYPE like Cash or Checks. I will just count the number of records that satisfies all the conditions.

Comment: `based on criteria or conditions stored on separate table` how exactly are you going to do that - store *logic* in a db table - let alone apply them to data in a text file?

Comment: Here is a sample code that I am currently doing to count all the rejected records from the text file.

Function ReadTextFile() As Integer
 Dim ctr As Integer = 0
 Dim str = Split(txtFile.Text, vbCrLf)
 For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(str) - 1
  If str(i).ToString.ToUpper Like "*" & <CONDITIONS FROM TABLE HERE> & "*" Then
   ctr += 1
  End If
 Next
 Return ctr
End Function

Comment: First code relative to the question needs to be in the question where it can be formatted and easily read.  Validation logic belongs on code, not in the DB

Comment: Thanks for the response Sir. I was able to make a remedy by first reading all the text files and save it to a table then created an SQL that includes all the conditions to filter the saved text file in the table.